# Is there anyway to speed up a long OPENQUERY

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

I am currently running an `OPENQUERY` that follows a structure similar to this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
P.x,
P.y,
etc...
FROM 
[DATA].[dbo].[dataP] P
inner join
OPENQUERY(localDb, 'SELECT ...
LEFT JOIN(...
Left join (...
INNER JOIN...
INNER JOIN(...') OQ
on (OQ.x = P.x)
where P.x > 0
```

Are there any better practices for optimizing an open query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a temp table or CTE to store the results of the OPENQUERY, and then join to it.

```
SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM OPENQUERY(localDb, 'SELECT ...
LEFT JOIN(...
Left join (...
INNER JOIN...
INNER JOIN(...') OQ
```

Then in your main query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
P.x,
P.y,
etc...
FROM 
[DATA].[dbo].[dataP] P
inner join
#temp as OQ
on (OQ.x = P.x)
where P.x > 0
```

It would also help to add any possible filtering conditions to your OPENQUERY to reduce the result set on the remote server.